ERROR [HY000] [Simba][Neo4j] (22) in connecting Power BI to Neo4j database using Simba ODBC driver
I've set up and connected Power BI to a Neo4j desktop database using Simba Neo4j ODBC driver. The connection works fine and I've imported some nodes and edges as tables and have built visuals connected to them. When I try to fetch a particular relationship, it fails to do so and throws the following error message:

Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] ERROR [HY000] [Simba][Neo4j] (22) An error has been thrown from the Neo4j client: 'could not run query: Neo4jError: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError (Invalid input '%': expected "TYPED" or an identifier (line 1, column 247 (offset: 246))
"MATCH (sourceNode0:Concept:Protein:Resource)-[relationship0:ortho]->(targetNode0:Concept:Protein:Resource) WHERE SIZE(LABELS(sourceNode0)) = 3 AND SIZE(LABELS(targetNode0)) = 3 RETURN ID(sourceNode0), ID(targetNode0), relationship0.%Identity_other, relationship0.%Identity_target, relationship0.Homology_type, relationship0.METHOD, relationship0.evidence, relationship0.iri, relationship0.ondexId"
^)'.
'.

It seems it is passing a wrong character in the Cypher query to the Neo4j, but why is it happening for this particular relationship only?

Do your ortho relationships have property names that begin with "%"? The ODBC driver may not be properly escaping all property names to avoid issues caused by special characters. You may want to ask the Simba folks for support.

Thanks for your comment, @cyersam. No, I don't have any property names beginning with a "%." I'm going to raise a ticket with them.
